How to run code asynchronously in a loop while inside a context manager?
I have written a small wrapper class around Playwright to easily take screenshots asynchronously. When I run the code, the print statements seems  to appear synchronously. I am new to async library so I am not sure what I may have done incorrectly. Here is a trimmed down code of what I want to do without the Playwright stuff. Here I was expecting for all of them to run together, but it runs one after another.
import asyncio
from random import randint

class Test():
    async def __aenter__(self):
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, *args):
        print("Exiting Context Manager")

    async def rand_sleep(self, id):
        print(f'Running: {id}')
        await asyncio.sleep(randint(1, 10))
        print(f'Completed: {id}')


async def main():
    async with Test() as t:
        for i in range(20):
            await t.rand_sleep(i)

if __name__=='__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

Here is the original playwright wrapper code
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import Browser
from playwright.async_api._generated import Playwright
from playwright.async_api._context_manager import PlaywrightContextManager



class Screenshot:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._playwright_context_manager: PlaywrightContextManager
        self._playwright_handler: Playwright
        self._browser_handler: Browser
        self._exit_called = False

    async def __aenter__(self):
        self._playwright_context_manager = PlaywrightContextManager()
        self._playwright_handler = await self._playwright_context_manager.__aenter__()
        self._browser_handler = await self._playwright_handler.chromium.launch()
        return self
    
    async def __aexit__(self, *args):
        if not self._exit_called:
            await self._browser_handler.close()
            await self._playwright_context_manager.__aexit__()
            self._exit_called = True

    async def get_screenshot(self, url, file_path):
        page = await self._browser_handler.new_page()
        print(f'Fetching {url}')
        await page.goto(url)
        await page.screenshot(path=file_path)
        print(f'Screenshot taken, closing {url}')
        await page.close()


async def main():
    from urllib.parse import urlparse
    import json

    with open('website-list.json', 'r') as f:
        websites = json.loads(f.read())

    async with Screenshot() as s:
        for url in [website['url'] for website in websites][:10]:
            file_path = 'screenshots/' + urlparse(url).hostname
            await s.get_screenshot(url, file_path)
            


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())


I though maybe the for loop is causing the problem, some online solution suggest using asyncio.gather, but for my problem I think it will exit the context manager before executing.

Is the problem playwright related? If not, please post a code not dependent on a 3rd party library. You are taking the screenshots in a for loop, i.e. sequencially. If you want any concurrency from asyncio, please read the docs or some tutorial about tasks - how they are created, awaited, or cancelled if need be.

hey, you are right. playwright did not have anything to do with the problem I was facing. I have added another code snippet that reproduces the same problem I am having. My understanding of asyncio is still immature, so I might be missing something.

@VPfB thanks to you I managed to solve it. After breaking down the problem it became much easier to diagnose it. :)

Turns out asyncio.gather was the correct way to do it. I messed up the first time implementing it. Here is how I implemented it on my demo code.
import asyncio
from random import randint

class Test():
    async def __aenter__(self):
        print("Entering Context Manager")
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, *args):
        print("Exiting Context Manager")

    async def rand_sleep(self, id):
        print(f'Running: {id}')
        await asyncio.sleep(randint(1, 10))
        print(f'Completed: {id}')


async def main():
    tasks = []
    async with Test() as t:
        for i in range(20):
            tasks.append(t.rand_sleep(i))
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks) 

if __name__=='__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

